# ¿Cómo puedo redondear a múltiplo en Python?

Tags: python

En PHP sé que es así pero en Python no consigo transformar la función:

**PHP:**

```
function roundBy($a, $b = 5) { 
    return (int)($a / $b + 0.5) * $b; 
}
```

**Python (Mal):**

```
def roundBy(a, b):
  return int((a / b + 0.5) * b)
```

**Input -> output esperado:**

```
30, 5 -> 30
31, 5 -> 30
32, 5 -> 30
33, 5 -> 35
34, 5 -> 35
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías dar algunos ejemplos del input y el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede redondear a múltiplos con la siguiente función donde `a` es el valor y `b` es el múltiplo al que redondear:

**Python - Ejemplo de función 1:**

```
def roundBy(a, b):
  return int(round((a%b)/b)*b)+(a - (a%b))
```

**Python - Ejemplo de función 2 (Mejor, más óptimizada):**

```
def roundBy(a, b):
  return int((a / b + 0.5)) * b
```

Return:

```
roundBy(30, 5) -> 30
roundBy(31, 5) -> 30
roundBy(32, 5) -> 30
roundBy(33, 5) -> 35
roundBy(34, 5) -> 35
```

Comment: Tu función original, tiene un paréntesis mal ubicado: `def roundBy(a, b=1):
  return int((a / b + 0.5)) * b`

Comment: esto no es una respuesta. Si eso, añade el contenido a tu publicación original.

Comment: Arreglado, espero que esté bien..

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes varias soluciones:

```
# con funcion 1
def roundBy(x, base=5):
    return int(base * round(float(x)/base))

# con funcion 2
def roundBy(x, base=5):
    return int(x) - int(x) % int(base)

# Sin funcion:

x=[30,31,32,33,34]
for b in x:
    print int(round(b/5.0)*5.0)
```

EDITO: Para las 3 opciones, el resultado es el mismo:

```
print roundBy(30,5)
print roundBy(31,5)
print roundBy(32,5)
print roundBy(33,5)
print roundBy(34,5)

Out[1]:
30
30
30
35
35
```

La 3 opción la veo menos eficiente, ya que podría aplicarse las funciones en algún paralel processing con `map` de la siguiente manera a diversos valores mas fácilmente:

```
valores=[30,31,32,33,34]

list(map(roundBy,valores))
Out[1]:
[30, 30, 30, 35, 35]
```

Comment: Hola Pecade. Puedes explicar las diferencias entre esas 2 funciones para que el autor pueda evaluar cuál le encaja mejor ? o son iguales ?

Comment: Hacen lo mismo, es decir el output es el mismo. podría hacerle un timing de performance para que vea cual le interesa mas, pero al final puede barajar usar cualquiera indiferentemente.